# Select multiple columns in current region to create bar chart using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, charts, multiple-columns, vba

Could anyone teach me how to select multiple columns in CurrentRegion property so that I can create a Bar chart based on it

Below are my progress so far.. however it doesn't work

```
Public Function FourthTable()

Dim Source As Workbook
Dim Search As Range
Dim CR As Range

SRT = "Service Request Tickets (IIT)"

Set Source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.xlsx")

Source.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set Search = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(SRT)

Source.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Search.Address).Offset(2, 0).CurrentRegion.Activate

ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Range("A:A, 
C:C").Resize(ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
'ActiveChart.SetSourceData  
Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Search.Address).Offset(2, 
0).CurrentRegion.Resize(CR.Rows.Count - 1, CR.Columns.Count)
ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DBarClustered
With ActiveChart
   .Perspective = 0
   .Elevation = 15
   .Rotation = 20
   .RightAngleAxes = True

End With

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Cut
With Sheets("Sheet2")
.Select
.Range("A34").Select
End With

ActiveSheet.Paste
Source.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Function
```

The error message i got was Application-defined or Object-defined error

The columns I wanted to select was Column A and Column C. I am unable to select the column by indicating the address of the cells such as "A34" or "C34" because the table data was generated using a program tools and thus the location of the table data is vary every time

The image below is the table data that I refer to

http://postimg.org/image/gu05epzm9/

Comment: Do you want to resize or select? 
    activecell.currentregion.column returns the column number of the activecell which is 2 rows below the cell where it finds srt. From there you are telling it to select Column A and C. I am sorry if i am missing something but i am unsure what you would like to do.

Comment: My intention is to select the entire table data by using CurrentRegion property and resize it so that column B and last row are not included in my selection. And from here i can create the bar chart based on my selection. I'm not sure whether I have done it correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
  Source.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Search.Address).Offset(2, 0). _
       CurrentRegion.Activate
```

Use this, which contracts the selected area so as to exclude the last row and last column of the data table:

```
  Dim tbl As Range
  Set tbl = Source.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Search.Address).Offset(2, 0). _
      CurrentRegion
  tbl.Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tbl.Columns.Count - 1).Select
```

While continuing to comment out or delete:

```
'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1). _
     Range(Search.Address).Offset(2,0).CurrentRegion. _
     Resize(CR.Rows.Count - 1, CR.Columns.Count)
```